# Creating connection pool using msnodesqlv8 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, connection

```
const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");
const connectionString ="server=SELT063;Database=AuthDB;username=sa;password=sa;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};pool:{max:100,min:1}";
sql.open(connectionString, function (err, conn) {
if(err){
    console.log("Error while connecting to DB :: "+err);
}

var pm = conn.procedureMgr();
pm.setTimeout(2);
sqlParams=[
    {
        "name": "Name",
        "type": "sql.varchar",
        "value": "ans"
    },{
        "name": "mob",
        "type": "sql.varchar",
        "value": "96"
    }];
  pm.callproc('GetUser',[sqlParams[0].value,sqlParams[1].value], function(err, 
results) {      
    if(err){
        console.log("Error in executing procedure :: "+err);
    }
    else{
        console.log('Procedure call success');           
        console.log(results);
    }
  });
})
```

I want to create a connection pool using msnodesqlv8 node package. But I am unable to understand how to do with. I have posted the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I [raised the issue](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/issues/87)but no reply almost after a week. Probably best use some other package that has better documentation and is more active